# Manipulate JSON data into cachet.io

Tags: json, laravel, cron

I have just set up a [Cachet](http://www.cachethq.io) status page but i am struggling to push updates to the components via it's [API](https://docs.cachethq.io/docs/update-a-component).

I am looking to take an existing JSON feed from a partner site and use this to update the status on my own page.

Here is a sample of the JSON data I need to pull:

```
{
    "state":"online",
    "message":"",
    "description":"",
    "append":"false",
    "status":true,
    "time":"Sat 23 Apr 2016 10:51:23 AM UTC +0000"
}
```

and below is the format Cachet uses in it's API.

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Component Name",
        "description": "Description",
        "link": "",
        "status": 1,
        "order": 0,
        "group_id": 0,
        "created_at": "2015-08-01 12:00:00",
        "updated_at": "2015-08-01 12:00:00",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "status_name": "Operational"
    }
}
```

Never dealt with JSON stuff before, but I guess i need a script that i can run every X mins to grab the original data and do the following:

- Convert the "state" from the original feed into Cachet ones.
- Update the "updated_at" time with the time the script was last run.

Any help or tutorial's would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the Lead Developer of Cachet, thanks for trying it out!

All you need to do is update the [Component status](https://github.com/CachetHQ/Cachet/blob/2.4/docs/component-statuses.md). Cachet will take care of the `updated_at` timestamp for you.

I'm unable to write the script for you, but you'd do something like this:

```
// This will be a lookup of the states from the service you're watching to Cachet.
serviceStates = [
    'online' => 1,
    'issues' => 2,
    'offline' => 4,
]

// The id of the component we're updating
componentId = 1

// The state that is coming back from the service you're watching
state = 'online'

request({url: 'demo.cachethq.io/api/v1/components/'+componentId, data: { status: serviceStates[state] }})
```

Pseudo code, but you should be able to work from that.

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for that, using your code I was able to grab the data from the external service and convert it into the status id's for cachet. Still can't figure out how to push this into Cachet

Comment: What language are you using? Make a `PUT` request to the Cachet endpoint.

Comment: Hi James, after some more tinkering i was finally able to figure this out - many thanks for the assistance! :)